# How to solve the problem about Grad Update in keras.model.fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've bulit a customized keras model consisting of some customized layers .When training,there are errors as follow likely to relate to grad update:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\AS\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 2326, in get_attr
    c_api.TF_OperationGetAttrValueProto(self._c_op, name, buf)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Operation 'conv2d_transpose' has no attr named '_XlaCompile'.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\AS\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\gradients_util.py", line 331, in _MaybeCompile
    xla_compile = op.get_attr("_XlaCompile")
  File "D:\AS\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 2330, in get_attr
    raise ValueError(str(e))
ValueError: Operation 'conv2d_transpose' has no attr named '_XlaCompile'.
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\AS\envs\tf2\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 1619, in _create_c_op
    c_op = c_api.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Depth of input (1) is not a multiple of input depth of filter (16) for 'gradients/conv2d_transpose_grad/Conv2D' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,10,10,1], [3,3,16,1].
```

A keras.backend.conv2d_transpose applied in the end of the model
It seems grad update in Keras only considers the whole model input

```
model.build(input_shape=en_in_shape)
```

I'm not clear about its specific grad update mechanism.How can I deal with this issue?
Thx!

my layer

```
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import conv_utils
from tensorflow.python.keras import constraints
from tensorflow.python.keras import initializers
from tensorflow.python.keras import regularizers
from tensorflow.python.keras import activations
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional_recurrent import ConvRNN2D
from tensorflow.python.ops import array_ops
from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.base_layer import Layer as Layer
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.recurrent import DropoutRNNCellMixin


class MyConvGRU2DCell(DropoutRNNCellMixin, Layer):
    def __init__(self,
                 filters,
                 kernel_size,
                 strides=(1, 1),
                 padding='valid',
                 data_format=None,
                 dilation_rate=(1, 1),
                 activation='tanh',
                 recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid',
                 kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
                 recurrent_initializer='orthogonal',
                 bias_initializer='zeros',
                 kernel_regularizer=None,
                 recurrent_regularizer=None,
                 bias_regularizer=None,
                 kernel_constraint=None,
                 recurrent_constraint=None,
                 bias_constraint=None,
                 dropout=0.,
                 recurrent_dropout=0.,
                 sample_mode='downsample',
                 de_kernel_size=None,
                 de_output_ch=None,
                 **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.filters = filters
        self.kernel_size = conv_utils.normalize_tuple(kernel_size, 2, 'kernel_size')
        self.strides = conv_utils.normalize_tuple(strides, 2, 'strides')
        self.padding = conv_utils.normalize_padding(padding)
        self.data_format = conv_utils.normalize_data_format(data_format)
        self.dilation_rate = conv_utils.normalize_tuple(dilation_rate, 2,
                                                        'dilation_rate')
        self.activation = activations.get(activation)
        self.recurrent_activation = activations.get(recurrent_activation)

        self.kernel_initializer = initializers.get(kernel_initializer)
        self.recurrent_initializer = initializers.get(recurrent_initializer)
        self.bias_initializer = initializers.get(bias_initializer)

        self.kernel_regularizer = regularizers.get(kernel_regularizer)
        self.recurrent_regularizer = regularizers.get(recurrent_regularizer)
        self.bias_regularizer = regularizers.get(bias_regularizer)

        self.kernel_constraint = constraints.get(kernel_constraint)
        self.recurrent_constraint = constraints.get(recurrent_constraint)
        self.bias_constraint = constraints.get(bias_constraint)

        self.dropout = min(1., max(0., dropout))
        self.recurrent_dropout = min(1., max(0., recurrent_dropout))

        self.state_size = (self.filters,)

        self.sample_mode = sample_mode
        if self.sample_mode is 'upsample':
            self.de_kernel_size = de_kernel_size
            self.de_output_ch = de_output_ch

    def build(self, input_shape):
        channel_axis = -1
        if input_shape[channel_axis] is None:
            raise ValueError('The channel dimension of the inputs '
                             'should be defined. Found `None`.')
        input_dim = input_shape[channel_axis]
        kernel_shape = self.kernel_size + (input_dim, self.filters * 3)
        self.kernel_shape = kernel_shape
        recurrent_kernel_shape = self.kernel_size + (self.filters, self.filters * 3)

        self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=kernel_shape,
                                      initializer=self.kernel_initializer,
                                      name='kernel',
                                      regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer,
                                      constraint=self.kernel_constraint)
        self.recurrent_kernel = self.add_weight(
            shape=recurrent_kernel_shape,
            initializer=self.recurrent_initializer,
            name='recurrent_kernel',
            regularizer=self.recurrent_regularizer,
            constraint=self.recurrent_constraint)

        self.bias = self.add_weight(
            shape=(self.filters * 3),
            name='bias',
            initializer=self.bias_initializer,
            regularizer=self.bias_regularizer,
            constraint=self.bias_constraint)

        if self.sample_mode is 'upsample':
            self.de_kernel_shape = self.de_kernel_size + (self.filters, self.de_output_ch)

            self.de_kernel = self.add_weight(
                shape=self.de_kernel_shape,
                initializer=self.kernel_initializer,
                name='de_kernel',
                regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer,
                constraint=self.kernel_constraint)

    def call(self, inputs, states, training=None):
        h_tm1 = states[0]

        dp_mask = self.get_dropout_mask_for_cell(inputs, training, count=3)
        rec_dp_mask = self.get_recurrent_dropout_mask_for_cell(
            h_tm1, training, count=3)

        if 0. < self.dropout < 1.:
            inputs_z = inputs * dp_mask[0]
            inputs_r = inputs * dp_mask[1]
            inputs_h = inputs * dp_mask[2]
        else:
            inputs_z = inputs
            inputs_r = inputs
            inputs_h = inputs

        if 0. < self.recurrent_dropout < 1.:
            h_tm1_z = h_tm1 * rec_dp_mask[0]
            h_tm1_r = h_tm1 * rec_dp_mask[1]
            h_tm1_h = h_tm1 * rec_dp_mask[2]
        else:
            h_tm1_z = h_tm1
            h_tm1_r = h_tm1
            h_tm1_h = h_tm1

        (kernel_z,
         kernel_r,
         kernel_h) = array_ops.split(self.kernel, 3, axis=-1)
        (recurrent_kernel_z,
         recurrent_kernel_r,
         recurrent_kernel_h) = array_ops.split(self.recurrent_kernel, 3, axis=-1)

        bias_z, bias_r, bias_h = array_ops.split(self.bias, 3)

        x_z = self.input_conv(inputs_z, kernel_z, bias_z, padding=self.padding)
        x_r = self.input_conv(inputs_r, kernel_r, bias_r, padding=self.padding)
        x_h = self.input_conv(inputs_h, kernel_h, bias_h, padding=self.padding)

        recurrent_z = self.recurrent_conv(h_tm1_z, recurrent_kernel_z)
        recurrent_r = self.recurrent_conv(h_tm1_r, recurrent_kernel_r)
        z = self.recurrent_activation(x_z + recurrent_z)
        r = self.recurrent_activation(x_r + recurrent_r)
        recurrent_h = self.recurrent_conv(h_tm1_h, recurrent_kernel_h)
        hh = self.activation(x_h + r * recurrent_h)

        h = z * h_tm1 + (1 - z) * hh
        if self.sample_mode is 'upsample':
            N = h.get_shape()[0]
            H = h.get_shape()[1] + self.de_kernel_size[0] - 1
            h_t = K.conv2d_transpose(h, self.de_kernel, output_shape=[N, H, H, self.de_output_ch])
            return h_t, [h, ]
        else:
            return h, [h]

    def input_conv(self, x, w, b=None, padding='valid'):
        conv_out = K.conv2d(x, w, strides=self.strides,
                            padding=padding,
                            data_format=self.data_format,
                            dilation_rate=self.dilation_rate)
        if b is not None:
            conv_out = K.bias_add(conv_out, b)
        return conv_out

    def recurrent_conv(self, x, w):
        conv_out = K.conv2d(x, w, strides=(1, 1),
                            padding='same',
                            data_format=self.data_format)
        return conv_out


class MyConvGRU2DLayer(ConvRNN2D):
    def __init__(self,
                 filters,
                 kernel_size,
                 strides=(1, 1),
                 padding='valid',
                 data_format=None,
                 dilation_rate=(1, 1),
                 activation='tanh',
                 recurrent_activation='hard_sigmoid',
                 kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
                 recurrent_initializer='orthogonal',
                 bias_initializer='zeros',
                 kernel_regularizer=None,
                 recurrent_regularizer=None,
                 bias_regularizer=None,
                 activity_regularizer=None,
                 kernel_constraint=None,
                 recurrent_constraint=None,
                 bias_constraint=None,
                 return_sequences=False,
                 go_backwards=False,
                 stateful=False,
                 dropout=0.,
                 recurrent_dropout=0.,
                 sample_mode='downsample',
                 de_kernel_size=None,
                 de_output_ch=None,
                 **kwargs):
        cell = MyConvGRU2DCell(filters=filters,
                               kernel_size=kernel_size,
                               strides=strides,
                               padding=padding,
                               data_format=data_format,
                               dilation_rate=dilation_rate,
                               activation=activation,
                               recurrent_activation=recurrent_activation,
                               kernel_initializer=kernel_initializer,
                               recurrent_initializer=recurrent_initializer,
                               bias_initializer=bias_initializer,
                               kernel_regularizer=kernel_regularizer,
                               recurrent_regularizer=recurrent_regularizer,
                               bias_regularizer=bias_regularizer,
                               kernel_constraint=kernel_constraint,
                               recurrent_constraint=recurrent_constraint,
                               bias_constraint=bias_constraint,
                               dropout=dropout,
                               recurrent_dropout=recurrent_dropout,
                               sample_mode=sample_mode,
                               de_kernel_size=de_kernel_size,
                               de_output_ch=de_output_ch,
                               dtype=kwargs.get('dtype'))
        super().__init__(cell,
                         return_sequences=return_sequences,
                         go_backwards=go_backwards,
                         stateful=stateful,
                         **kwargs)
        self.activity_regularizer = regularizers.get(activity_regularizer)

    def call(self, inputs, mask=None, training=None, initial_state=None):
        self._maybe_reset_cell_dropout_mask(self.cell)
        return super().call(inputs,
                            mask=mask,
                            training=training,
                            initial_state=initial_state)

    @property
    def filters(self):
        return self.cell.filters

    @property
    def kernel_size(self):
        return self.cell.kernel_size

    @property
    def strides(self):
        return self.cell.strides

    @property
    def padding(self):
        return self.cell.padding

    @property
    def data_format(self):
        return self.cell.data_format

    @property
    def dilation_rate(self):
        return self.cell.dilation_rate

    @property
    def activation(self):
        return self.cell.activation

    @property
    def recurrent_activation(self):
        return self.cell.recurrent_activation

    @property
    def kernel_initializer(self):
        return self.cell.kernel_initializer

    @property
    def recurrent_initializer(self):
        return self.cell.recurrent_initializer

    @property
    def bias_initializer(self):
        return self.cell.bias_initializer

    @property
    def kernel_regularizer(self):
        return self.cell.kernel_regularizer

    @property
    def recurrent_regularizer(self):
        return self.cell.recurrent_regularizer

    @property
    def bias_regularizer(self):
        return self.cell.bias_regularizer

    @property
    def kernel_constraint(self):
        return self.cell.kernel_constraint

    @property
    def recurrent_constraint(self):
        return self.cell.recurrent_constraint

    @property
    def bias_constraint(self):
        return self.cell.bias_constraint

    @property
    def dropout(self):
        return self.cell.dropout

    @property
    def recurrent_dropout(self):
        return self.cell.recurrent_dropout
```

my model

```
class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self,
                 kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 filters1=16,
                 filters2=32):
        super().__init__()
        self.en_layer1 = MyConvGRU2DLayer(filters1,
                                                         kernel_size,
                                                         dropout=0.,
                                                         recurrent_dropout=0.,
                                                         return_sequences=True,
                                                         return_state=True)
        self.en_layer2 = MyConvGRU2DLayer(filters2,
                                                         kernel_size,
                                                         dropout=0.,
                                                         recurrent_dropout=0.,
                                                         return_sequences=False,
                                                         return_state=False)

        self.fo_layer1 = MyConvGRU2DLayer(filters1,
                                                         kernel_size,
                                                         dropout=0.,
                                                         recurrent_dropout=0.,
                                                         return_sequences=True,
                                                         return_state=False,
                                                         sample_mode='upsample',
                                                         de_kernel_size=(3, 3),
                                                         de_output_ch=1,
                                                         )
        self.fo_layer2 = MyConvGRU2DLayer(filters2,
                                                         kernel_size,
                                                         dropout=0.,
                                                         recurrent_dropout=0.,
                                                         return_sequences=True,
                                                         return_state=False,
                                                         sample_mode='upsample',
                                                         de_kernel_size=(5, 5),
                                                         de_output_ch=1,
                                                         )

    def call(self, en_inputs,):
        en_hid1, en2fo1 = self.en_layer1(en_inputs)
        en2fo2 = self.en_layer2(en_hid1)

        fo_inputs = en_hid1 * 0
        fo_hid2 = self.fo_layer2(fo_inputs, initial_state=[en2fo2])
        pred = self.fo_layer1(fo_hid2, initial_state=[en2fo1])
        return pred
```

dataset test

```
def model_bulid(en_in_shape,):
    model = MyModel()
    model.build(input_shape=en_in_shape)
    return model

h_seq = tf.constant(tf.random.uniform([4,2,10,10,1]))
f_seq = tf.constant(tf.random.uniform([4,2,10,10,1]))
num_epochs = 1
en_in_shape = (2,2, 10, 10, 1)

test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((h_seq,f_seq)).batch(2)
```

compile & fit

```
model = model_bulid(en_in_shape, )
print(model.summary())

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.mse,
    metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.sparse_categorical_accuracy]
)

model.fit(test_dataset, epochs=num_epochs)
```

Comment: It would be nice to share a reproducible code. Its hard to debug from the above information.

Comment: ok.I've put my code and hope you see it.